# 'autoconf' 2.50 not found when compiling 'mate-common' 1.15.0

Tags: compiling, mate, autoconf

I wanted to compile `mate` 1.15 on Ubuntu 16.04, but when I run `./autogen.sh` in `mate-common-1.15.0` it outputs this :

```
checking for autoconf >= 2.53...
testing autoconf2.50... not found.
testing autoconf... found 2.69
```

The rest works well.

So I searched in Synaptic and I didn't find a package named "autoconf2.50".
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply install it without a version number added:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```